# RDP changes Windows Server 2012 R2 time

Tags: remote-desktop, sync, windows-server-2012-r2, time

We have a server setup in different country from where we are. We RDP to the Windows Server (2012 R2). We are in a different time and timezone from the Windows Server. However every now and again the time changes to our local time while the time zone stays correct. We strongly suspect Remote Desktop is the culprit for the following reasons:

1. Internet time sync is disabled on Windows Server
2. Daylight savings has been disabled on Windows Server
3. Host to VM sync has been disabled on vmWare Host
4. ESXi host time is correct in any case

The Windows server just runs our Application, it is in no way a Domain controller, and those roles haven't even been installed.

Any ideas where to check if RDP is syncing the time? Or some other possible solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by assigning a NTP server to match your other server time zone this way it wonlt be able to change time once you force it .